# If I z-score all continuous variables of a linear mixed effects model, can I report the beta weights of the fixed effects as r values?

Tags: mixed-model

I have model that looks something like this

```
continuous_response ~ continuous_predictor1 + continuous_predictor2 + continuous_predictor1*binary_predictor + continuous_predictor2*binary_predictor + random_effect1 + random_effect2
```

If I z-score each of the continuous predictors and the response variable, am I right to think I can report the values of the beta weights for the interactions and the main effects as *r* values?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an "*r* value."  These coefficients are known as "standardized coefficients" and "partial correlations," btw.

Comment: Actually this may answer my question. Just to be clear are you saying that in my case, they could be referred to as BOTH standardized coefficients OR partial correlations? I guess I should not just report "r = ..." since that implies a non-partial correlation